# How to optimize a function with two variables such that the constraint is satisified

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

I have a hollow bar with outer diameter  `d1` and inner diameter `d2`. One end of the bar is fixed and the other is subjected load. Due to this load bending stress are generated in the bar and it is given by
\begin{align}
            \sigma=\frac{M c}{I_{xx}} \label{eq:stress}
\end{align}
I am interested in reducing this stress for any given value of `M`. The form of `c` and `Ixx` is given by
\begin{align*}
            c=\frac{d_{o}}{2};\quad I_{xx}=\frac{\pi (r_{o}^4-r_{i}^4)}{4} 
\end{align*}
The outer and the inner radius `r1` and `r2` are related by below equation
\begin{align}
            r_{o}-r_{i}=t
            \label{eq:const} 
\end{align}
Now my objective is to minimize the stress `σ`. which I have written as `f` such that the constraint is satisfied
\begin{align}
            f&=\frac{4Mr_{o}}{\pi(r_{o}^4-r_{i}^4)}\\
\end{align}

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
d1 = 2*r1;(*outer diameter*)
d2 = 2*r2;(*Inner diameter*)
aixx = Simplify[(π (d1^4 - d2^4))/64];
sigmax = Simplify[(M*r1)/aixx];
f = sigmax; (*opjective function*)
r1 = r2 + t; 
Minimize[{f, r1}, {r2, t}]
```

Comment: Your `g` is not a constraint, and `t` is not defined.

Comment: @Hausdorff actually `r1` and `r2` are related by `t`. and I have slightly modified the OP is that OK

Comment: You don't need the constraint anymore, you can just write `Minimize[f, {r2, t}]`

Comment: @Hausdorff I am getting wired results. I don't know whether I have framed the problem properly or not. Could you suggest any changes in the problem statement

Comment: I don't know what problem you are trying to solve, maybe you could elaborate a bit in your question.

Comment: @Hausdorff please look at the OP I have edited now with a clear problem ststment

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you were trying to achieve:

```
d1 = 2*r1;
d2 = 2*r2;
aixx = Simplify[(\[Pi] (d1^4 - d2^4))/64];
sigmax = Simplify[(M*r1)/aixx];
f = sigmax
Simplify @ Minimize[{f, r1 == r2 + t && t > 0 && r2 > 0}, {r2}]
```

or

```
Simplify @ Minimize[{f, r1 == r2 + t && t > 0 && r2 > 0}, {r2, t}]
```

if you also want to minimize w.r.t. the thickness.

Comment: Could able to interpret the obtained result. I am beginner in optimization. could you briefly tell me what to understand the result

Comment: @acoustics The result is, frankly, bogus. I think you need to re-think the problem itself because it's probably ill-defined right now.